# oracle integration repository package

Tags: web-services, oracle

I am new to Oracle and have been having trouble following instructions for importing a package into the integration repository.

The instructions include code for creating a package and body, but don't really tell me what to do with that code. It looks like I should run it in SQL Plus. Is that correct?

It also includes instructions for generating the ILDT file--but only in a generic way. Those instructions just refer me to the "SOA Gateway Implementation Guide". (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e12169/T511175T543269.htm) The command is:

$IAS_ORACLE_HOME/perl/bin/perl $FND_TOP/bin/irep_parser.pl -g -v -username=sysadmin itg:patch/115/sql:fndav.pls:12.0=/tmp/fndav.pls

I'm not sure what to use for the .pls file. Is that generated and then the ILDT file is also created?

Apologies for this newbie question.

I appreciate any help!

Thanks,

Sami

Answer (score 0):

You probably figured this by now, as per oracle conventions .pls file is the package specification and .plb is for package body.